# Algorithmic complexity of checking if an element exists in an array

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, computation-theory

If I have an array of unsorted numbers and a number I'm looking for, I believe there's no way of checking if my number is in it except by going through each member and comparing.

Now, in mathematics and various theoretical branches I've been interested in, there's often the pattern that you usually get what you put in. What I mean is, there's usually an explanation for every unexpected result. Take the Monty Hall problem as an example. It seems counter-intuitive until you realize the host adds more information into the situation because he knows what door the car is behind.

Since you're iterating on the array, instead of just getting a yes or no answer, you also get the exact location of the element (if it's there). Wouldn't it then make sense that there's an algorithm that's less complex, but give you ONLY a single bit of information?

Am I completely off base here?

Is there an actual correlation between the amount of information you get and the complexity of an algorithm? What's the theory behind the relationship between the amount of information you get from an algorithm and it's complexity?

Comment: what's a single bit of information?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what's being asked here.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys A yes or no answer to the question "Is this number in this array?"

Comment: You can, actually, determine if a number is in an array in `O(1)` time... if you do work up front utilizing an appropriate data structure. An 'array' is simply one data structure you can use, and if it is unsorted there no 'constraints' you can rely on to determine what is in it: hence you're off base IF you are using an unsorted array. http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear to me. There is too much knee-jerk closure of questions on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are searching an array, indexing is the price that you pay for having an array. An ability to access an element by index is inherent in the structure of the array: in other words, once you say "I am going to search an array" (not a collection, but specifically an array) you have already paid for the index. At this point, there is no way to get rid of it, and the `O(n)` cost associated with searching the array.

However, this is not the only solution: if you agree to drop the ability to index as a requirement, you could build a collection that gives you a yes/no answer much faster. For example, if you use a hash table, your search time becomes `O(1)`. Of course there is no associated index in a hash table: inability to access items in arbitrary order is your payment for an ability to check for presence or absence of items in constant time.

Comment: Right! That completely slipped my mind. The choice of the data structure limited the amount of "fine grained control" I have over the complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're completely off base, sorry!

Algorithmic complexity is defined in terms of how many operations it takes to solve the problem of size N. If the array has N elements in it, then there is no way of determining whether the value appears in the array other than checking all N elements. That makes it linear, or O(N).

The fact that you can *also* determine the location of the value in O(N) (as indeed you can) doesn't mean that you can solve the simpler problem in less time.

Comment: That's too bad. I was hoping there would be more to it in a theoretical sense. I guess stack overflow isn't really a place for discussions and open ended questions like this. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @LukaHorvat The last paragraph touches on the underlying theory. Problems come in shades of *hardness*: How much of some resource must be spent to solve an instance of the problem? This is not a strict order: Many problems are *equally* hard, even if one (where, if anywhere, is this value in this array?) is more general than the other (does this value occur in this array?). Each of those problems can be proven to have some specific complexity, and the proof goes almost identically for the two problems. Seeing as there are such proofs, your question isn't really open ended.